# Javascript/Jquery UNDEFINED textarea value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I run a website and there is an area to send messages with AJAX. I've noticed that some messages say undefined and therefore people can't use the message system. The following is the code used to get the value from the text area, whats wrong with it ? I'm thinking that some browsers don't accept it so how can I fix it? Thanks

```
<textarea id="message"></textarea>
$('textarea#message').val()
```

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/8abfr/). I think the problem lies elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `val()` method get the value attribut, but tag textarea has no value attribut. The text inside Textarea is saved inside the tags `<textarea>` and `</textarea>`, so you have to use `$('textarea#message').text()`. It should work.

Comment: `text()` returns the original text inside the textarea, which is *not* the same as the current value (actually it should be the same as `textarea.defaultValue`). Except in IE due to bugs. There is almost never any good reason to use `text()` on a textarea. jQuery `val()` and the underlying JavaScript property `textarea.value` do exist and return the current value of the field.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <textarea >some text</textarea >

   not like this

   <textarea value="some text"></textarea >
```

**There is no value attribute**

```
  <textarea id="message"></textarea>
  $('textarea#message').text();
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadtarawneah/7Wytg/)